# Automapper: Any reason to prefer fully typed mapping function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I've been using Automapper with AspNetCore for a bit now.

I just became aware that there's actually quite a few functions available on the `IMapper` interface.

Specifically, I realized I've been mapping using the function

`public TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)`

while another function (with more defined type parameters) is available as

`public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)`

.

Now that I'm aware of both choices, I'm wondering if there's any benefit - performance or otherwise - to using the more verbose function over the one I am now.

This would mean changing my calls to `Map` from

`mapper.Map<TDestination>(sourceObject)`

to

`mapper.Map<TDestination, TSource>(sourceObject)`

.

[Here's the source of the two functions for reference](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Mapper.cs)

```
   public TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)
    {
        var types = new TypePair(source?.GetType() ?? typeof(object), typeof(TDestination));

        var func = ConfigurationProvider.GetUntypedMapperFunc(new MapRequest(types, types));

        return (TDestination) func(source, null, DefaultContext);
    }

    public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)
    {
        var types = TypePair.Create(source, typeof(TSource), typeof (TDestination));

        var func = ConfigurationProvider.GetMapperFunc<TSource, TDestination>(types);

        var destination = default(TDestination);

        return func(source, destination, DefaultContext);
    }
```

I would assume the form with the more verbose Type parameters would be more efficient, but it's very possible that the performance difference would be too small to be significant.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Being more explicit, it makes it easier to see what map might apply. The runtime type of the source object is always used (unless it's null) but that only matters if you also have derived maps. About the performance, measure if you really care. For value types, it certainly makes sense to avoid the `object` overload.